# Javascript console in mobile WebView

Tags: javascript, mobile, webview, console.log

I have a webpage that I want to show in a WebView embedded in a mobile application (for Android as well as iPhone). That webpage is for testing javascript scripts. The page calls a certain set of JS scripts (tests) and these tests give their output into the console (this is where I can diagnose what happened during the tests). Using console.log. Plus exceptions are shown in the console.

When the tests fail, the JS error handler will notify me about and I can show that fact on my webpage so that I can see it on the phone. But I also need to look at the JS console to understand what went wrong.
How do I access the JS console on the phone when the test result tells me it failed?

One option that I was thinking about was to output the content of the console somehow into the webpage content (DOM) so that I can look at it in the app (in the embedded webview since it would be the content of the page shown). But I don't know whether it is possible in Javascript to output the console into HTML somehow.

I do not develop the mobile application, just deliver the content that the application shows in the WebView. Therefore I would need a solution that does not depend on the application itself, just have something I can see in the WebView ideally. Something like when you debug your javascripts in Chrome, you open the DevTools window and work with it. If there was no DevTools on Chrome, would there be a way to see the contents of the console?

Sure I can use various simulators or do the test on other browsers without real phones but this is specifically for tests that fail only on the mobile and I need to find out why.

Comment: Changing the `console.log` function is what I always do, just set it to render to a div element on the page that you can toggle when needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work : connect your phone to your computer in debugger mode and open on your computer Chrome in Developer mode (chrome://inspect). You should be able to see your phone and maybe the app webview for debugging

Comment: The idea with changing the console.log function is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Android:

Maybe this link should help you : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Using the Chrome dev mode on your computer, you should be able to debug your webview

About IPhone, I don't know but Xcode or something like should help